How to extend session.user in Auth.js?
Below follows a question on Auth.js (formerly NextAuth.js).
Background:
I am using the jwt session strategy, but would still like to store more information about a user on session.user, than what is saved on the jwt by default (default: name, email, image). For instance, I would like to add a role and and the organization they belong to. Following the docs, I have done module augmentation to extend the types of the jwt and session.user.
Goal:
I have read the section on Extending the Session in the docs, but it only explains how to get the extra session data if it comes from the provider (i.e. Google). In my case, I would like to do a lookup in a database, in order to augment session.user.
Question:
How can the above goal be achieved? Do I just do the database call inside the provider's profile callback, or inside the jwt callback?
Since I am anyways calling the database on login/logout, am I loosing the leanness/scalability benefits of the jwt session strategy, and might just as well use the database session strategy directly?

Quite possible
Let's say you are going to add role prop.
To be able to use our own session props, we need to add type folder at the root level of the project and put next-auth.d.ts file inside it
import { DefaultSession } from "next-auth"

declare module "next-auth" {
    interface User {
        id: string
        email: string
        role: string
    }

    interface Session {
        user: User & DefaultSession["user"]
        expires: string
        error: string
    }
}

As to callback functions
async jwt({ token, user, account, trigger, session }) {
    if (account && user) {
        token.id = user.id
        token.email = "admin@admin.com"
        token.role = "Administrator"
    }
    return token
},
async session({ session, token }) {
    return {
        ...session,
        user: {
            ...session.user,
            id: token.id as string,
            email: token.email as string,
            role: token.role as string,
        }
    }
}

That's it!

Perfect, that is similar to what I did. Thank you. If the session data I wanted to add came from a database, would you just do the database call inside the jwt callback, then grab the value from the token in the session callback? I.e. is it ok to reach out to a database within these callbacks?

I added another question here (which I suspiciously think someone working against the library purposefully down/close-voted): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78788233/in-which-callback-should-user-data-be-added-to-a-database-in-auth-js

Let's say you use Credentials Provider along with a database adapter with jwt approach. In that case, you do the operations you've mentioned in sign in callback. Please take a look at: https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth/discussions/4394#discussioncomment-4949531

That discussion you linked is great. I do think they fixed a lot of it, after looking in the source code. A jwt, aka. session token, is created automatically for credentials, similarly to oauth. The only difference is that for oauth, Auth.js automatically creates a user in the database (if adaper is set), and a few other things (like checking if another user with same email already exists, etc.). You probably know all that. I wish they would add the handleLoginOrRegister(..) to the Credentials flow as well.

PS: I decided to create the new user, if it does not exist, in authorize(), even though it should technically be done after signIn() is called, but before jwt(), if we want it to match the oauth flow.
